# ¿Como liberar una tabla de un loop infinito en un Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Estaba trabajando con un Stored Procedure en MySQL. Hay un momento en el que inserto en una misma tabla varias veces con un `WHILE`. Sin embargo, la primera vez que lo probe se me olvido declara la condición que rompería ese ciclo y ahora esa tabla ya no me responde. No puedo hacerle consultas, ni inserciones, actualizaciones ni nada.
Estoy intentando truncarla y también se queda pensando.

Se que esto está pasando únicamente con esta tabla porque cualquier otra tabla si me permite hacer operaciones (lo cual también significa que no tengo problemas de conexión ni nada por el estilo).

¿Qué puedo hacer para liberar la tabla?

Comment: Se me ocurre reiniciar la instancia, ¿lo has intentado?

Comment: Se puede matar el proceso, pero depende si tienes acceso y permisos; o si hay un DBA.